# How to sell Android app to a general contractor for my desired price?

Tags: working-from-home, programmer, company-management, local-business

I have designed an app specifically for a certain contracting company on the Android Studio platform. I have recently looked over the regulations for uploading an app onto the Google Play store and have concluded that it would not be in my best interest to do so because I am selling to one company only (as of now). Any suggestions as to how I should go along this process and how to dodge giving the company all the rights over the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload the app and create the feature for selling its services, so while they pay you a subcription or a one time payment thru the app or outside they will have access to your app and services.

Comment: Upload the whole project onto one of their computers or how so? Also how would I create a feature for selling the app's services if all the services are there already?

Comment: In Apps Purchases (IAP), this how I would do it. In my splash screen, will check with the IAP service if the current logged account has purchased the use of the application features. If so ignore next screen and the app will be full open, if not then it redirct to a screen where it would ask for pay for the use of the app using IAP, kind of like a license. The will be uploaded to Play Store and then set up the IAP service there, documentation available at adndroid development console support.

Comment: Also using play store test release of the app you can make it private so only people you add will be allowed to use. Another way you can add a type of api service on the app so that you can control its functionality if they dont pay you. Kind of: api.allowUseOfApp() == false -> showWarningAndLRestrictUse();